# How many live uncommitted transactions MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

The isolation level MySQL is set **REPEATABLE READ**

**Пример работы:**

```
START TRANSACTION;
(1000 INSERT QUERY);
(1000 SELECT QUERY);
COMMIT;
```

What happens if the COMMIT is not executed?
How long will hang this transaction in memory and wait for confirmation?
Where is configured lifetime of the transaction?
After all, if it does exist for some time, there may be a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in force until the connection is closed.

MySQL utilizes [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-real-connect.html) and [interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout). But unless the client sides are written to employ it, there is little use in testing against it with any client you typically have, such as MySQL Workbench or the client utilities.

> What happens if the COMMIT is not executed?

Everything waits until the above transaction holder connection status is dealt with.

> How long will hang this transaction in memory and wait for confirmation?

Potentially forever.

> Where is configured lifetime of the transaction?

There is none.

> After all, if it does exist for some time, there may be a memory leak?

Sure. This is a comment, not a question.